# NULL treated as decimal in union query?

Tags: mariadb

See this query (MariaDB 10.11.4)

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT field_a as number, field_b as name FROM my_table;

DESCRIBE temp_table;
```

Which outputs

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| number | bigint(20) unsigned | NO |  |  |  |
| name | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |

But as soon I do a `UNION` to a dummy data:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
select field_a as number, field_b as name from my_table
union
select null as number, 'dummy' as name from my_table;

DESCRIBE temp_table;
```

Now the datatype for `number` changes from `bigint(20) unsigned` to `decimal(20,0)`

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| number | decimal(20,0) | YES |  |  |  |
| name | varchar(50) | NO |  |  |  |

Why is that?

I've solve it by casting that `null`, but I wonder if there's something I can tweak instead of editing my query statement (there are too many!)

```
select field_a as number, field_b as name from my_table
union
select cast(null as unsigned) as number, 'dummy' as name from my_table;
```

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE
  `my_table` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `field_a` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,    
    `field_b` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Is the problem about `NULL` or about the dropped `unsigned` keyword?

Comment: @Progman I'm sorry that was a simple copy and paste mistake. But the example works fine for the sake of the explanation. My query is much more large, by far!!! but the problem happend in the union and null

Comment: @Progman the problem is that I rely on the data type. In MariaDB 10.1.44 this worked fine. I expected a bigint and that is what I received.

Comment: besides the rows with data, I also get the cols with datatype. So I rely on the correct datatype in order to be show correctly in the UI

Comment: The behavior depends on the type of `mytable.field_a`.

Comment: @Luuk but `field_a` is bigint

Comment: Maybe you should create a [bug](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs/)  (seeing the output of this DBFIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/-NW2RuU-)

Comment: You have to use CAST to have specific datatype from NULL. The BIGINT and DECIMAL(20,0) are pretty much the same datatype (the decimal one can contain larger values). If your application depends on the datatype, treat DECIMAL datatype with zero scale as *INT.

Comment: Found a bug report [MDEV-21662](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21662) and added a simpler test case, please vote/watch bugs of interest to given them priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as [@danblack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10195153/danblack) pointed out, this is a [bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21662). I going to leave this here in case anyone stumble with this issue